# How to use tsDyn::star while dplyr is loaded?

Tags: r, dplyr

The sample code from [tsDyn::star](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/tsDyn/docs/STAR) doesn't work when `dplyr` is loaded

```
library(tsDyn)
library(dplyr)
mod.star <- star(log10(lynx), mTh=c(0,1), control=list(maxit=3000))
# Error in lag(x, lags[i]) : n must be a single positive integer
```

This seems to be because [dplyr::lag](http://www.inside-r.org/node/230640) overwrites base lag. `tsDyn::star` does work if `dplyr` is detached:

```
detach("package:dplyr")
mod.star <- star(log10(lynx), mTh=c(0,1), control=list(maxit=3000))
# Testing linearity...   p-Value =  0.0001831653 
# The series is nonlinear. Incremental building procedure:
# Building a 2 regime STAR.
# Performing grid search for starting values...
```

How could I keep using dplyr pipes and data modification verbs while using `tsDyn::star`?